# Eclipse IDE compile error

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting the following error from Eclipse IDE when it tries to compile:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'XXXX'.
3
```

In one of my Java files I'm also seeing:

```
Internal compiler error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at 
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.fields(SourceTypeBinding.java:721)
```

That error is at the very top of the Java file, it's underlining the "p" in package as an error. I have tried deleting the file that gives this error but I still end up with the same compile error, it simply flags a different file with the same error.

I've been trying to resolve this for about 1 day now. I've deleted my .metadata folder ( running with the -clean param ) and re-imported all my projects, removed various libraries and re-added them, also I've updated to Eclipse 4.4M6. All of the above and I still get the same error.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this, or even how I should attempt to resolve it now? I'm not having much luck searching google for resolutions for this error. It's very frustrating as I cannot build my projects at all!!

Comment: Looks like Eclipse bug [392871](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392871) which is not resolved.

Comment: Yes, that does seem like the bug. Looks like they are having a little trouble reproducing it. 

Shame it doesn't mention any fix for the issue. It's strange that it just occurred when I had no done anything major to my Eclipse project.
Thanks for find the bug reference!

Answer (score 0):

Typical Eclipse bugs, I had/have/will have this kind of error many times. Make sure you have *Build automatically* checked in *Project* menu. Then do *Project > Clean*. If this doesn't solve the problem, restart Eclipse (*File > Restart*).

Comment: I have tried this many times, it persists through restarts and after doing _Project > Clean_

I do also have _Build automatically_ checked.

Comment: Try deleting the project (don't delete in disk) and importing it again.